# Flutter install in windows environment variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problem when trying to install the flutter in my desktop first I get error of :

is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.

Then I open the system environment variable and add the flutter to the user variables path plus I add all of the flutter, git, system32 to systems variables path section.

Unfortunately, the problem is still present even with a restart.

Now when I type flutter doctor to Command prompt No results are shown and I cannot write an extra line.

Comment: Try setting the environment variable of your system

Comment: I try but same problem

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should take these steps:

1. Open RUN by shortcut `(WINDOWS_KEY+R_KEY)`
2. Type in RUN `SystemPropertiesAdvanced`.
3. System Properties dialog should appear, click `Environment Variables`.
4. In User variables (The Top section) select `Path` and click Edit.
5. Add the new path to flutter Binary folder like this `C:\flutter\bin`.
6. Select OK, and OK again in Environment Variables, and OK in System Properties.
7. Close any Command prompt you using and reboot the system.
8. Now flutter is successfully installed.